# How can i get id of data populated in list inflator from database in a listview

Tags: android, database

I have a custom list view with editext and check box .Data is populated from database into the list and I need to check which check box is checked and store id of that populated textview of that checked checkbox into database .

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final TestListPojo objTest = testList.get(position);
    final String testitem = objTest.getTestname();
    barcode = objTest.getBarcode();
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(myContext);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.testlist_inflator,
                null);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.test = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.test);
        holder.ch_check = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.ch_check);
        holder.et_barcode = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.et_testbarcode);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        if (!barcode.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !(barcode == null)) {
            holder.et_barcode.setText(barcode);
            /*for (int i = 0; i < barcode.length(); i++) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(barcode);
                // StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(barcode);
                String save=sb.append(",").append(i).toString();


            }
*/
        }

    }

    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    final TextView test = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    holder.test.setText(testitem);
    holder.test.setClickable(true);
    holder.test.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        test.getText().toString();
        System.out.println(test.getText().toString());

        }
    });

    holder.ch_check
            .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    CheckBox ch = (CheckBox) buttonView;
                    if (ch.isChecked()) {

                        /*ch.get
                        System.out.println(ch.getImeActionLabel().toString());
*/
                    }

                }
            });

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView test;
    CheckBox ch_check;
    EditText et_barcode;
}

}

| testname1   barcode1   checkbox |
| testname2   barcode1   checkbox |
|   '            '            '   |
|   '            '            '   |
|                                 |
|                                 |
```

testname and barcode are populated from database and I need to check which test is selected or not. And update that this test is selected in db.

Comment: If you want an answer always post your relevant code.

Comment: You need to set onItemClickListener for your listview and when an item is clicked it will send you the position and id of the clicked item

Comment: I am getting position id but i need to update the populated textview using id in my database and update that particular textview value .

Comment: Do you get the index of the row being clicked?

Comment: Yes i am getting the index....

Comment: what is the name of your adapter? And what kind of adapter? ArrayAdapter or SimpleCursorAdapter or...

Comment: Base Adapter i am using

Comment: Post your onCreate code and hopefully someone will help you. I am going to sleep it is 1:30 AM here.